# Manifolds of maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sobolev-spaces, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Suppose $M$ is a compact $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary. Let $H^s(M,M)$ denote the Sobolev space on $M$, defined as all maps from $M$ to $M$ whose distributional derivatives up to order $s$ are square integrable. For $s>n/2+1$, let $$\mathcal{D}^s =\{\eta\in H^s(M, M)| \eta ~\text{is bijective and}~ \eta^{-1}\in H^s(M,M)\}. $$ Define right multiplication
\begin{align}
 R_\eta:\mathcal{D}^s \to\mathcal{D}^s \\
\xi\to\xi\circ\eta.
\end{align}
Why is $R_\eta ~C^{\infty}$ for each $\eta \in \mathcal{D}^s$?

Also, if define left multiplication
\begin{align}
L_\eta :\mathcal{D}^s \to\mathcal{D}^s \\
\xi \to \eta \circ\xi.
\end{align}
Why is $L_\eta$ only $C^l$ when $\eta\in \mathcal{D}^{s+l}$?

Essentially what is the difference between $R_\eta ~\text{and} ~L_\eta$?

Comment: If you consider the same operator for Sobolev maps defined on a vector space, right multiplication is **linear** and thus smooth, whereas left multiplication is not. This might be part of the explanation.

Comment: Thanks! The conclusion makes sense, since the right multiplication is linear which is naturally smooth, while the regularity of left multiplication depends on the regularity of $\eta$.

Answer (score 3):

To go a bit more into the details (elaborating on Thomas comment above):
The result on the differentiability order is classical (going back to Ebin's work in the 60s, culminating in the seminal paper by Ebin and Marsden: Groups of diffeomorphisms and the motion of an incompressible fluid, Ann. Math., 92(1970), 102-163). However, recently the result was established again in great detail in the paper [On the regularity of the composition of diffeomorphisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0488).

For a closed manifold the space $H^s (M,N)$ ($s$ bigh enough) carries a Hilbert manifold structure via the usual manifolds of mappings construction (where charts are constructed using a suitable local addition, aka. the Riemannian exponential map, cf. Kriegl, Michor: [The convenient setting of global analysis](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf) for an explanation of the construction for the manifold of smooth mappings  (instead of Sobolev type). The upshot of this construction is however, that there is a canonical identification of the tangent manifold of the manifold of $H^s$-mappings:
$$TH^s(M,N) \cong H^s (M,TN).$$
Now $\mathcal{D}^s \subseteq H^s (M,M)$ inherits its smooth structure from the ambient space and in particular we have an induced identification $T\mathcal{D}^s \subseteq H^s (M,TM)$. Under this identification it is not hard to deduce the following identifications
$$TR_\eta (f) = f\circ \eta , \qquad TL_\eta (f) = T\eta \circ f, \quad f \in H^s (M,TM).$$
Here of course $\eta$ needs to be in $H^{s+1}$ for the second formula to make sense, whereas for the first formula we can savely assume that $\eta \in \mathcal{D}^s$. Thus whenever $s< \infty$ we see that every derivative of the left multiplication looses one order of differentiability of the map $\eta$.

Of course the right multiplication is also continuous linear, whence smooth. But to me the above formula makes it explicit how one is loosing orders of differentiability on $\mathcal{D}^s$ (which is thus not a Lie group but only a [half Lie group](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.07728)).